# Android Studio UI elements missing between

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I started the android tutorials on my laptop while I was away on a trip. Among the first parts it includes learning how to contraint and autoconnect in layout mode, using this picture as a reference.[image: observe the eye and magnet]

This worked with my laptop. However, when I open my desktop Android Studio, which I had installed months prior, these elements are missing.

[image]

I thought this may be a result of an out of date, so I uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled the newest version to no avail. How does one go about fixing this.

Comment: Don't you see the dialog notifying about updates? Have you updated SDK and other components?

Comment: "Installed months prior" == "out of date"

Comment: I ran those updates as well

Comment: cricket, at the bottom i said i uninstalled and reinstalled to newest version as said in bottom

Comment: So this issue disappeared, but only by having to restart with a new project. For my previous project I had worked on with my laptop that still does not work with the viewer showing constraint or autoconnect.